# How do I create a star rating system?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to create a star rating system using JQuery. It should save my rating once I'm done rating it. I've written this so far.

```
<input id="rating-system" type="number" class="rating" min="1" max="5" step="1">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to do star rating but I can give you an example.
The example can be found here.
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3.html